# convert epoch time for count down timer in java

Tags: java

Let's say some one clicked on some button and at that moment I save the current epoch time(let's say: 1653421487183).

And I want to allow an next click on the button withing 4Hours and 5Minutes(which is: 14700000),
Which mean the next Click will be available at: `1653421487183 + 14700000` epoch time.

According to that data, I want to use that time singature to show an timer.

the next click will be available in: 04:04:59, 04:04:58 and more...

How can I parse the epoch time to look like a count down timer given the formula `(remaining_time_until_the_next_click - currentEpochTime)`,
which Should be like that: `1653436187183-currentEpochTime`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time*

Java includes the *java.time* classes for such work. No need to work with clumsy count of seconds/milliseconds from an epoch reference.

Capture the current moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

```
Instant then = Instant.now() ;
```

Later, capture the current moment again.

```
Instant now = Instant.now() ;
```

Calculate elapsed time on a scale of hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between ( then , now ) ;
```

### Counting down

You want to countdown to a future moment. So define the span of time to wait as a `Duration` object.

```
Duration wait = Duration.ofHours( 4 ).plusMinutes( 5 ) ;
```

Add to the current moment.

```
Instant target = Instant.now().plus( wait ) ;
```

When you want to report time remaining, capture the current moment and calculate another `Duration` object.

```
Duration timeRemaining = Duration.between( Instant.now() , target ) ;
```

Test to see if that duration is negative. If so, that means we overshot the target time, with the current moment being after the target time.

```
if( timeRemaining.isNegative() ) { … }
```

### Generating text

I recommend using the standard ISO 8601 format for reporting such values.

```
String output = duration.toString() ;
```

Such strings can be parsed directly.

```
Duration d = Duration.parse( "PT4M56S" ) ;
```

I recommend against using the clock time format as such text is ambiguous, easily mistaken for a time-of-day value rather than elapses down of time.

But if you insist on using clock time format, assemble your string using parts retourne by the `to…Part` methods.